# use calculus to maximize the area of a triangle

Tags: calculus

What is the maximum area of a triangle that can be inscribed in a circle with radius of $5$ units. Solve using calculus. 
Is there a way to use $A = 0.5 \times b \times h$ and take the derivative?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you familiar with multivariable calculus and Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: Clearly not. I think she is just using basic differential calculus @fractal1729

Comment: Right that makes sense.  I do think it gets a little trickier if one is constrained to single variable calculus only though.  The problem is equivalent to maximizing $\sin a + \sin b + \sin c$ given that $a+b+c = 2\pi$.

Comment: Never mind, I am being silly.  I do think there's a nicer way to do this.

Comment: It is easier to solve it without using Calculus. Assume that $A,B,C$ are three points on the same circle: by moving $B$ along the $AC$ arc, the area of $ABC$ is maximized when $B$ is exactly the midpoint of the major $AC$ arc (the area depends on distance of $B$ from the $AC$ chord). It follows that the maximum area is achieved by equilateral triangles and equilateral triangles only.

Answer (score 1):

Let the radius be $r$ for now.  Suppose that side $BC$ of our triangle $ABC$ has length $x$.

Then if we consider orienting the circle such that $BC$ is horizontal and on the bottom half, then point $A$ should be at the top of the circle, in order to maximize the area by maximizing the height.

Thus we only really need to consider isosceles triangles.  Let $O$ be the center of the circle and consider $OA$, $OB$, and $OC$ which divide the triangle into three smaller ones.  By the area formula $ab\sin(C)/2$, these triangles have area $r^2\sin(\angle AOB)/2$, $r^2\sin(\angle BOC)/2$, and $r^2\sin(\angle COA)/2$.  If we let \angle $BOC$ be $2\theta$, then $\angle AOC = \angle AOB = \pi - \theta$.

Hence the area of $ABC$ is the sum of the three areas which is $$r^2(\sin(2\theta) + 2\sin(\pi-\theta)) = r^2(\sin(2\theta) + 2\sin(\theta)).$$

This is a single variable function that we can nicely maximize by taking a derivative.  It is fairly straightforward to show that the maximum occurs when $\theta = 60$, or the triangle is equilateral, so the area becomes $3\sqrt{3}r^2/4$.

In your case the maximum area is $75\sqrt{3}/4$.